# Textarea com as linhas do tamanho do texto

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap

Podem me ajudar?

Tenho uma função JavaScript que aumenta o tamanho do textarea conforme digitamos o texto e damos ENTER. Até aí, tudo ok.

Entretanto, ao puxar esta informação do banco de dados, o textarea não vem com seu tamanho respeitando o tamanho do texto.

Segue exemplo para tentar ilustrar melhor:

Problema:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Ideal:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
<textarea class="form-control" readonly>{{ $resposta->resposta }}</textarea>
```

Saberiam como resolver? Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É só ajustar a altura do textarea pela altura do scroll que ela tiver:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){
   var txtarea = document.querySelector("textarea.form-control");
   txtarea.style.height = txtarea.scrollHeight+"px";
});
```

```html
<textarea class="form-control" readonly>linha 1
linha 2
linha 3
linha 4
linha 5
linha 6</textarea>
```

Comment: Olá! Obrigado pela sua resposta. Quando escrevo no html puro a mensagem, ele retorna com o tamanho da linha correto. Mas quando trago a informação do banco de dados, não. Pelo que vi ao inspecionar o elemento, o js está carregando antes do sistema puxar os dados do banco. Então ele carrega vazio.

Cheguei até a colocar esse js no final da página, ainda assim, ele carrega antes. Saberia como contornar isso?

Comment: Achei meu problema. Havia um outro textarea logo em cima, então ele estava contando as linhas deste primeiro, e não do que tinha logo abaixo. Defini uma classe diferente para cada um e pronto. Solved! Muito obrigado pela ajuda!!